# Tableau 8.2 with Bigquery, how to do automatic authentication refresh?

Tags: google-bigquery, tableau-api

Tableau 8.2 desktop version.   We refresh the dashboard every 4 minutes(with AutoIt script to actually execute click and F5), but every around half an hour, it pops up this dialogue requesting a manual activation of bigquery authentication. How could we avoid this issue? We need this refreshing all automatically all the time.

[image: Invalide username or password]

**Solved**
I originally used 8.2.0 desktop version. This issue was solved by upgrading it to 8.2.3 desktop version.
Thank all of you for help.

Comment: are you the Tableau 8.2 developer?

Comment: I'm not doing any development on Tableau, just using tableau to build up statistic dashboard. Not sure if that's what you asked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Tableau documentation](http://onlinehelp.tableausoftware.com/current/pro/online/mac/en-us/oauth_connect.html#connect-oauth) you need Tableau Server for that:

> Note: If you have not published your workbook or data source to a
>   Tableau server, you are not able to embed OAuth credentials to bypass
>   authentication and connect directly to the data. For information about
>   using embedded OAuth credentials with published workbooks and data
>   sources, see the next section, OAuth on Tableau Server, and the
>   related topics.

BTW If you have Tableau Server, [read this article](http://downloads.tableausoftware.com/quickstart/feature-guides/oauth_google.pdf) for help on getting Oauth set up.

Comment: Thank you so much. It's been fixed by upgrading to 8.2.3 desktop (I originally used 8.2.0)